# Server Side Include trouble in HTML document on Brackets

Tags: html, adobe-brackets

I have been trying to incorporate my navigation bar into each page of my website using a server side include. My goal is to be able to just change one file and each page would have the amendment. I have recently asked a question about this and got a solid response: `<!--#include virtual="menu.cgi" -->` or `<!--#include file="footer.html" -->`

This sounds like it works great but in my coding editor, brackets. It treats this as a comment and therefore does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server Side Includes, as their name suggests, are a feature of a web *server*.

They shouldn't "work" in a text editor. That is just a tool to let you edit the code. (And the syntax is designed to be the same as HTML comment syntax so that tools handling plain HTML will treat them as comments).

Test your code using a web server.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have a question. On Brackets text editor it has live edit mode where I have been viewing the website as its in development. When you say use a web server does the live mode where it shows the website count? If not can you give me an example of a web server I should use?

Comment: See [the documentation for Live Preview mode](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Use-Brackets). You need to use the "Using your own backend" approach. Use whatever web server you were going to use in production if you can.

Comment: Thanks I'll let you know how that works. I downloaded Mamp so backend code could be processed